# UrlMapping :: View attribute in matched block ignored

Tags: grails, view, url-mapping

Given URI /admin/article/index, why would this url mapping not work?

```
"/admin/$controller/$action?/$id?"{ 
        view = "/admin/index" // no dice, ignored 
        //action = "foo" // uncommented, this is picked up 
}
```

I'd like for all admin controllers to use the admin view by default (and not have to render the view in each action of each controller). Same goes for "/account/$controller/..." and any other site module that should use a common view.

Perhaps there's another way to achieve this, but assumed that UrlMappings is the place to do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do something very different than what you wrote.

You already have the `action` mapped in the base URL mapping, and the view is automatically selected based on the `controller`, so you need to [define *different* mappings](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.4%20URL%20Mappings) for those views that don't have a controller, and yet another mapping for items with a default action of `foo`.  The default action on controllers is `index`, though, so there is usually no need to supply a default action without also specifying a controller.

I think you are, in general, misunderstanding how an MVC framework works.  The controller should not be rendering anything, and the views should be specific to the controller/action.  If multiple *controllers* are rendering the exact same view, I'd be willing to bet that either the controller is rendering HTML or the view is overly complicated.

You should look into [Layouts with SiteMesh](http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/6.%20The%20Web%20Layer.html#6.2.4%20Layouts%20with%20Sitemesh), which allows you to create default template structures, then just have the specific content change through views.

Comment: Thanks, foo action does nothing, just verifying urlmapping block was actually matched. Yes, what I'm trying to do goes against MVC grain. Since every controller under /admin will use the exact same view, it seems pointless to create duplicated views in order to satisfy controller to action.gsp convention. Admin screens are all exactly the same (dashboard, breadcrumb, autocomplete search, etc.), the only varying content being the forms themselves, which I am more than happy to <tmpl:/$controller/$action /> in admin layout + admin view. Perhaps this is a wrong approach, just starting with views.

Comment: Yes, that's all what layouts are for. See the last link.

Comment: Sure, layouts are for exactly that, but for each controller I'll still need to define a view-action.gsp (or per controller action render admin template), which is not terribly DRY given that, again, the only varying content is controller form content.

Comment: I'm confused.  The only difference from action-to-action is the form content, so you want one large view with all the forms in it, instead of a shared layout and view for each action?  The layout should contain all the duplicated code (barring the layout tag in the view).

Comment: Yes, I want one admin view and layout (which create the html skeleton that defines dashbar, breadcrumbs, etc.) with controller-action forms <g:include'd> or <tmpl'd>. The content that varies is controller-action form; the only reason I see to create controller-action views is to satisfy grails convention of rendering default view based on controller-action, which seems more hindrance than help in this case.

Comment: OK, just did a generate-views for a test domain. Now I see, scaffolded view-action GSPs describe the entire page, including header, CRUD navigation, and form content. Looks like with install- templates I can strip things down to form content only, leaving skeletal bits to admin layout. Thanks for hanging in there, tried Grails 1.2 and 1.3, but never got beyond GORM due to reloading issues and sloooow compile times; with 1.4+ virtually the entire app is runtime reloadable, so actually enjoying Grails ;-)